# GCC Compiler - potential difference between Code Blocks and Mac OSX (XCode)?

Tags: c, macos, gcc, compilation, codeblocks

Recently, my friend asked me to help him with his coding assignment.  I tried compiling his C code to help him through the debugging process, but it didn't compile, and instead returned the following error:

> Assignment 3.c:12: error: conflicting types for ‘random’
>
> /usr/include/stdlib.h:224: error: previous declaration of ‘random’ was here
>
> Assignment 3.c:51: error: conflicting types for ‘random’
>
> /usr/include/stdlib.h:224: error: previous declaration of ‘random’ was here

So, I get that what this means is that there is a "random" function already defined within the stdlib.h (header file), but what I don't get is why it compiled for him perfectly fine.  The difference is that he was using Code Blocks, whereas I was using my Mac OSX terminal (GCC).  From what I know, the two both use GCC compiler, so I'm wondering why there is a discrepancy.  Any clarification would be great.  Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
Some code sample to explain the error. The random() shown here  is for line 12.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void readColsRows(int* cols, int* rows);
int** allocMemory(int* minima, int* maxima,int rows, int cols);
void random(int*** table, int rows, int cols);
void maxMinFinder(int** table, int* minima, int* maxima,int rows, int cols);
void printTable(int** table, int rows, int cols);
```

I didn't want to put all the code up here because it is for a homework assignment.  :X  However, I think my question may have been answered by Jonathan Leffler in the comments below.  Thanks!

Comment: does "`random`" exist on your friend's copy of "`/usr/include/stdlib.h`"?

Comment: Oh, stdlib.h can have different functions across different copies?

Comment: There is nothing called `random` in the code you've shown.  And it doesn't have 12 lines, so how can anything be wrong on line 12?  Please give us the information we need to help you.

Comment: Your code shows `random1()` but the question discusses `random()`...was this the hacked version of the code that you modified to make it work?  POSIX (or, at least, the Single Unix Specification) defines a function [`random()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/random.html) provided by the system library and declared in `<stdlib.h>`. Consequently, you have to turn off the POSIX source functions to avoid the clash.  Lots of code uses systematic prefixes to functions to avoid clashes with functions in system libraries on other machines. Renaming is probably best.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan.  I believe that is the answer I am looking for.  I apologize for all the mistakes and confusion in my question.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost give yourself the answer:

The standard library (as indicated in /usr/include/stdlib.h at line 224) defines `random` as

```
long     random(void);
```

whereas you do:

```
void random(int*** table, int rows, int cols);
```

Obviously, there is a conflict that the compiler flags. Select a different name. The problem is not related to codeblocks.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  :D  I think Jonathan answers the question in the comments above.  :)

Answer (score -1):

On Mac, some header files include other header files that are not included on other operating systems. For example, if you include `iostream` on Mac, `stdlib.h` is included, too. On Linux, this is not the case.

Comment: I don't think this is quite the case, since the stdlib was included directly.  :X